# webapp2 routes for external links

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I want to manage external links in a central place in my app so that if they change I need only change them in one place.

Since I'm already using webapp2s routing, I figured I could use that, and use url_for just like every other link. So, tried the following:

```
Route('http://www.google.com', name='google', build_only=True)
```

but when I render the link, like this:

```
uri_for('google')
```

It encodes the http:// bit, like this:

```
http%3A//www.google.com
```

which means if you use it in a href tag, you end up with a relative link like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/some/path/http%3A//www.google.com
```

So, questions are:

- Is webapp2s routing even designed for external links?
- If yes, how to you add absolute URLs?
- If no, is there a similar mechanism for doing so?

Would be nice to use webapp2s routing so I can seamlessly use url_for without having to write another 'same but different' method.

Comment: Maybe this works : add _full=True giving uri_for('google', _full=True)

Comment: @voscausa thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work. the _full param forces the method to return an an absolute url derived from the current server address, which is not what i needed. I managed to solve the problem by overriding the uri_for method and using urllib.unquote() to decode the string back. i will add an answer explaining. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by implementing my own uri_for method, and using that instead

```
def uri_for(_name, _request=None, *args, **kwargs):
    uri = webapp2.uri_for(_name, _request, *args, **kwargs)
    return urllib.unquote(uri)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of _full (as voscausa mentioned above), you can put _netloc with the server name when calling uri_for.  Putting _netloc  forces _full to True.

See http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#uri-routing